# How to write IE property Hacks with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, properties

I am writing jQuery animation for a cross-browser view effect. I need to tackle IE with the hack property `_height` and `*height`. I try to set the property with

```
$('#notice_container').css({'_margin-bottom':'auto', 'margin-bottom': '31px'});
```

But it doesn't set `_margin-bottom` as I specified althrough `margin-bottom` is set.

So, my questions are how to set those IE specified properties with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a direct answer of how to implement traditional IE CSS hacks with jQuery, you might be interested in a cleaner solution, outlined here:

http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Basically, you use conditional comments to assign classes to the `html` element depending on which version of IE is running:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then target elements like this rather than using hacks:

```
$('.ie7 #notice_container').css({'margin-bottom':'auto'});
```

Choose ids if you want or different class names. This is a very clean approach to "hacking" IE in general.

Comment: This the most elegant solution, doesn't need to pollute my JS with browser detection and IE hacks. Thanks!

Comment: You can toss out those conditional stylesheets too and write the IE stuff in with your normal CSS, much more maintainable.

Comment: +1 though i suggested ie conditional comments but this explains it better for you

Answer (score 2):

Why you can try is

```
if( $.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7.0 )
{
    $('#notice_container').css({'margin-bottom':'auto'});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the style attribute directly:

```
 .attr({'style':'_margin-bottom:auto;margin-bottom:31px'});
```